# How screeching affects the body?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, neuroscience, physiology, terminology

Most times when I hear a screech (such as moving a sharp object on a chalkboard thereby causing such unpleasant noise), my body twitches. There are also other unpleasant sounds that causes the twitching, but whenever it sounds only my dad, my brother and I that feels it, but my two sisters and my mum says they don't feel anything. My question is:

**Is there any scientific term for this feeling?**

**Is it hereditary?**

**What happens in the body or brain when the sound is produced?**

Comment: Me too feel this; but rarely on chalk-board. It is more common if I slide a stainless-steel-spoon on a stainless steel dish. The sound is not bad but it induce a strange "uneasy" or "discomfort" feeling on my palms, thumbs, the ventral surface of hand, armpit, the side of body; and sometimes includes chest, interior of hands, spine, legs etc. I don't know why this happen; but many others report this. The susceptivity to this, varies from day to day, and sometimes only the vision (not even sound) before the screatch, induce this sensation.

Comment: This also happens to me if someone screetches finger on paper (for say while someone is reading or demonstrating from a book) when I was unprepared to follow the finger of the reader. Also the strength of this sense in me depends upon the 'look' or 'pattern' of finger-holding of the reader. I don't know is their any name or identification of it; but it really happens. It might be some sort of illusion. These illusions were much stronger when I was kid. I was scared of it.  With age, these irritating illusions became much milder.

Comment: Why this downvote?

Comment: This is the answer: http://www.livescience.com/16967-fingernails-chalkboard-painful.html.